# TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) Django manage.py runserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, manage.py

I tried running

```
manage.py runserver
manage.py makemigrations
and manage.py migrate
```

but they all give me a TypeError

The error is

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/perputer/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/perputer/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Start over/Simple/perputer/words/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Word(models):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I haven't changed my manage.py
and my models.py that's causing the error:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Word(models): <-- error
    word = models.CharField(max_length = 26)
    meaning = models.TextField(help_text = "A definition for the word attached to it.")
    language = models.CharField(max_length = "20", editable = True)
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: its models.Model instead of models

Answer (score 1):

`models` is a *module*, not a class. [The *class* is `django.db.models.Model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model). Change the import to:

```
from django.db.models import Model
```

and define the class with:

```
class Word(Model):
```

Any time you see this error (`TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`), it's because you inadvertently tried to inherit from a module, not the class it contains.